# Autocomplete \cite without using bibtex (embedded system)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, texmaker, auto-completion

I'm writing a report without using BibTeX. I'm using the `\cite{}` command to cite the references found in my bibliography, which I define using the `thebibliography` environment. Is there a way to have Texmaker autocomplete `\cite{}`, knowing that I'm getting no errors? For example, Texmaker would provide autocompletion when I use `\cite{Example}` for a `\bibitem[He \& and She, 2015]{Example} bla bla`.

EDIT: I'm using Texmaker as my editor. Here's an example of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
In their paper, \cite{Example} found that 1+1 equals 2
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\paragraph{ \\}
\bibitem[He \& She, 2015]{Example} This is the reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The quesion is not yet clear to me. Can you make an full example (MWE)? What are you using to generate the bibliography, when not using `bibtex` (`biber` or manually created bibliography)?

Comment: It's just that I'm making the analogy with `\caption` and `\ref` commands that I use for figures. Auto-completion is available for `\ref` once I add a `\caption` to any figure

Comment: I don't particularly think this is unclear: it is a question about the editor configuration, though, so the editor should be in the question and not an afterthought.